# exception in Linq to sql

Tags: linq-to-sql, exception

my query is :

```
var ReadAndUnreadMessages =
        (from m in MDB.Messages
         orderby m.Date descending
         where m.ID_Receive == (Guid)USER.ProviderUserKey && m.Delete_Admin == false
         select new AllMessages()
         {
             id = (LoadMessageChildren(m.ID_Message)[LoadMessageChildren(m.ID_Message).Count - 1] as Message).ID_Message,
             parent = (Guid)(LoadMessageChildren(m.ID_Message)[LoadMessageChildren(m.ID_Message).Count - 1] as Message).ID_Message_Parent,
             sender = (LoadMessageChildren(m.ID_Message)[LoadMessageChildren(m.ID_Message).Count - 1] as Message).ID_Sender,
             receiver = (Guid)USER.ProviderUserKey,
             subject = (LoadMessageChildren(m.ID_Message)[LoadMessageChildren(m.ID_Message).Count - 1] as Message).Subject.Subject1.ToString() == "Other" ?
                           (LoadMessageChildren(m.ID_Message)[LoadMessageChildren(m.ID_Message).Count - 1] as Message).Other_Subject
                           :
                           (LoadMessageChildren(m.ID_Message)[LoadMessageChildren(m.ID_Message).Count - 1] as Message).Subject.Subject1.ToString(),
             body = (LoadMessageChildren(m.ID_Message)[LoadMessageChildren(m.ID_Message).Count - 1] as Message).Body.Length > 26 ?
                     (LoadMessageChildren(m.ID_Message)[LoadMessageChildren(m.ID_Message).Count - 1] as Message).Body.Substring(0, 25) + "..."
                     :
                     (LoadMessageChildren(m.ID_Message)[LoadMessageChildren(m.ID_Message).Count - 1] as Message).Body,
             date = (LoadMessageChildren(m.ID_Message)[LoadMessageChildren(m.ID_Message).Count - 1] as Message).Date.ToShortDateString(),
             read =(LoadMessageChildren(m.ID_Message)[LoadMessageChildren(m.ID_Message).Count - 1] as Message).IsRead,
             finished = (LoadMessageChildren(m.ID_Message)[LoadMessageChildren(m.ID_Message).Count - 1] as Message).IsFinished,
             count = MessageClass.LoadAll(m.ID_Message).Count
         }).ToList();
```

and exception is :

> The argument 'value' was the wrong type. Expected 'Message'. Actual 'System.Object'.

what does meaning it?

LoadMessageChildren :

```
public static ArrayList LoadMessageChildren(Guid Parent)
{
    ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
    Guid id = Parent;
    while (id != Guid.Empty)
    {
        arr.Add(LoadMessage(id));
        try
        {
            id = (Guid)MDB.Messages.Single(a => a.ID_Message_Parent == id).ID_Message;
        }
        catch
        {
            id = Guid.Empty;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

LoadMessage :

```
public static Message LoadMessage(Guid id)
{
    var mess = from m in MDB.Messages
               where m.ID_Message == id
               select m;

    return mess.Single();
}
```

Comment: every thing is OK , I make class data and write this query,I send you Only part of Code .

Comment: Could you post the function `LoadMessageChildren`? The error can be there, or even in one of the property setters. Do you have a stack trace that shows the error is here?

Comment: LodMessageChildren Method return a ArrayList

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is unreadable, and as a bad case of code repetition (and multiple executions of `LoadMessageChildren`).
For starters, consider the following:

```
from m in MDB.Messages
     orderby m.Date descending
     where m.ID_Receive == (Guid)USER.ProviderUserKey && m.Delete_Admin == false
     let children = LoadMessageChildren(m.ID_Message)
     let lastChildMessage = children.Last()
     select new AllMessages()
     {
         id = lastChildMessage.ID_Message, 
         ...
     }
```

This may solve your problem, as it is [might be caused by using the `[]` indexer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/eed81cc3-6338-4418-b79f-60846520e21f).
Aside from that, it is not clear the posted code is causing the exception.

Comment: LodMessageChildren Method return a ArrayList

Comment: In that case, you can do `let children = LoadMessageChildren(m.ID_Message).Cast<Message>()`. ArrayLists don't play well with linq, as they are untyped, but it's workable. If possible, try to run the line `var messages = LoadMessageChildren(m.ID_Message).Cast<Message>().ToList();`. If that doesn't work, it's the cause of your problem.

Comment: I try that and this exception is appeared :"No coercion operator is defined between types 'System.Collections.ArrayList' and 'Message'."

Comment: You should consider changing LoadMessageChildren so it returns a List<Message> rather than the non-generic ArrayList.

Comment: I edit my post and add two method . loamessagechildren and loadmessage

Comment: @mohammad reza - It looks like you have many, many problems. You have good suggestions here, and every one lead to a whole new exception. I doubt the solution lies is the code you've posted... It looks like LoadMessageChildren is adding a string (or an object) to your array list, but no one can know for sure. I suggest you break your code into bits and test every part independently (unit test your code). As for the question - you've put a bounty and didn't choose an answer, mine was automatically accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The error is most likely caused by the use of the `ArrayList`.

The problem is that LINQ was designed to work with generic collections that implement the `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` interface. The `ArrayList` is a nongeneric collection that internally stores everything as an [Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx). So when you retrieve something from the ArrayList you need to cast it to a `Message`. 
Looking at your error message it looks like somewhere a `Message` object is expected, but the instance in your ArrayList (an `Object`) is not casted to a `Message` object when that reference occurs. Also, the `ArrayList` does not implement the `IEnumerable<T>` interface which might get you into trouble in certain situations also.

How to fix it?

I suggest changing the implementation of your `LoadMessageChildren` to use a [generic list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) (`List<Message>`):

```
public static List<Message> LoadMessageChildren(Guid Parent)
{
    List<Message> arr = new List<Message>();
    Guid id = Parent;
    while (id != Guid.Empty)
    {
        arr.Add(LoadMessage(id));
        try
        {
            id = (Guid)MDB.Messages.Single(a => a.ID_Message_Parent == id).ID_Message;
        }
        catch
        {
            id = Guid.Empty;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

You will have to make also change the code that interacts with the generic list in terms of retrieving/referencing items. But that is just syntax. Since equivalent methods for dealist with lists and items exist.

There are also advantages in terms of performance and compile-time validation for switching from `ArrayList` to `List<T>`. The `ArrayList` is basically an inheritance from version 1.0 of the .Net Framework when there was no support for generics and it just get kept in the framework probably for compatibility reasons. 
There are greater [benefits for using generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5bx6xee.aspx).

***UPDATED ANSWER:***

The "*Method 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[Message] LoadMessageChildren(System.Guid)' has no supported translation to SQL*" exception that you are getting is caused by the fact that your `LoadMessageChildren` method is not mapping to a stored procedure or a user defined function in your database.

You cannot have any regular C# method call inside your LINQ to SQL queries. The [LINQ to SQL object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bb386989.aspx) interprets a method found inside your query as either a stored procedure or a user defined function. So the engine is basically looking for a method called `LoadMessageChildren` that maps to a stored procedure or a user defined function in your database. Because there are no mappings, it tells you that `no supported translation to SQL` was found. The [LINQ to SQL object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bb386989.aspx) link shows you how to use method attributes to map a method that executes a stored procedure.

You have a few choices now:

1. create stored procedures of your regular C# method calls
2. rewrite your LINQ query to use `joins` to select child messages

Comment: this exception is appeared :
Method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Message] LoadMessageChildren(System.Guid)' has no supported translation to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see you using LoadChildMessages() for in the end is to get the child message count... Unless I am wrong I would think you could write it as a join. You doing a lot of queries with in queries that don't seem necessary and are probably causing multiple hits to the database. My question to that would be why isn't there a relationship in your dmbl/sql database so that LinqToSql knows to create a property as a `List<Message> ChildMessages`

But here is my take:

```
var query = from message in MDB.Messges
            join childmessage in MDB.Messages.Where(child => child.ID_Message_Parent == message.ID_Message) into childMessages
            from childMessage in childMessages.DefaultIfEmpty() // This creates a 
            // left outer join so you get parent messages that don't have any children 
            where message.ID_Receive == (Guid)USER.ProviderUserKey && message.Delete_Admin == false
            select new AllMessages()
            {
                id = message.ID_Message,
                parent = message.ID_Message_Parent,
                sender = message.ID_Sender,
                receiver = (Guid)USER.ProviderUserKey,
                subject = message.Subject.Subject1.ToString() == "Other" ?
                           message.Other_Subject
                           :
                           message.Subject.Subject1.ToString(),
                body = message.Body.Length > 26 ?
                     message.Body.Substring(0, 25) + "..."
                     :
                     message.Body,
                date = message.Date.ToShortDateString(),
                read =message.IsRead,
                finished = message.IsFinished,
                count = childMessage.Count() // This might have to be this
                //count = childMessage == null ? 0 : childMessage.Count()
            };

var ReadAndUnreadMessages = query.ToList();
```

But it's hard to say because I can't run the code... Please respond and let me know if this works.

**Note:** May I suggest using a class that links to your DataContext.Log property that writes the generated TSQL code to the debugger window. Here is an article on [writing your own](http://www.u2u.info/Blogs/Kris/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=11). It has really help me know when I am making unnecessary calls to the database.